# How can I see the diff for an edit I have made before it is approved?

Tags: support, feature-request

When I edit someone's question, I have to wait for the edit to be approved before the link that says when the question was edited and links to the changes appears if I want to see the changes I have made. However, I'm most likely to want to see my changes before it is approved. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Well when you edit the question you'll see it in the preview box below the text editor with which you are performing the edit. It's exactly the same for when you post a question, comment, answer, or perform an edit you'll see what you're typing and/or editing before said post/edit is tossed up on the site for all to gawk at...

What I mean is this, you have the text box to type in and all, then below that it'll display it as a preview so you can see how it'll look when your question, answer, comment, or edit is posted. Granted only you and the mods will see it till it's approved but at least you'll get an idea of how it'll look to other folks if & when it's approved.

Comment: I already knew about this; I was hoping for a way to the version where is shows deleted text in red and added text in green. Thanks anyways though :)

Comment: Ah gotcha....yeah I sort of agree with you, that'd be a neat idea :)